# I need help applying this command to all files and subdirectories, "echo "text" | tee -a *"

Tags: bash, shell

`echo "text" | tee -a *`, when I use this command, it adds "text" to all file and file types in the directory I am in, I want to apply this command to all files in my directory and all subdirectories and I tried a command like this, `find. -type f -exec echo "text" | tee -a * {} \;` The reason I used this command was because the find command could cover the directory and all its subdirectories, but I couldn't run it with the "find" command :(

Could you write an alternative command (with its parameters, detailed for the purpose I mentioned)? Or can you fix the error in the command I wrote and throw it to me?

Comment: `and all subdirectories` and all subdirectories of those subdirectories recursively, or just subdirectories?

Comment: all subdirectories of those subdirectories recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you write an alternative command

```
find . -type f | xargs -d '\n' sh -c 'echo "text" | tee "$@"' _
```

> Or can you fix the error in the command I wrote and throw it to me?

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "text" >> "$1"' _ {} \;
```